# Wrap tab-right-aligned text on the right margin in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, alignment, word-wrap

I want text with a dot leader and right align tab to wrap on the right margin. Word will wrap a long line to the left, like this:

```
You Are the New Day, We Are the New Day......John David,  
arr. Peter Knight
```

But what I want is this (the line breaking wherever the margin is, of course), where whatever text that doesn't fit on the first line is right-aligned in the next line:

```
You Are the New Day, We Are the New Day......John David,  
                                       arr. Peter Knight
```

Is it possible for Word to do this without manual intervention?

Comment: I wonder if you can right-align the whole line, but then insert a left-align tab between the two parts of the line? (maybe a right-align tab works as VSRawat answered?)

Answer (score 0):

Select all the lines, Click Control-R 
or 
from Menu - Home - Right Align (appears in "paragraph" area).